# How to check if username is already exist in database in django and show the error "username is already taken "in template html page

Tags: python, django

I'm new in Django and web develoment. So, I have a custom user model looks like this in my models.py

```
class MyAccount(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    club_favorite = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    object = MyAccountManager()
    
    USERNAME_FIELD =    'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'club_favorite', 'email']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True
    
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
    
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, first_name, middle_name, last_name, club_favorite, email, password=None):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a username")
        user = self.model(
            username = self.normalize_email(username),
            first_name = first_name,
            middle_name = middle_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            club_favorite = club_favorite,
            email = email,
        )
        
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, username, first_name, middle_name, last_name, club_favorite, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            password = password,
            first_name = first_name,
            middle_name = middle_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            club_favorite = club_favorite,
            email = email,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

from views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if(request.method == "POST"):
            first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
            middle_name = request.POST.get('middle_name')
            last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
            password2 = request.POST.get('password2')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            club_favorite = request.POST.get('club_favorite')
            
            user = MyAccount.object.create_user(first_name, middle_name, last_name, username, password1, email, club_favorite)
            user.save()
        
            return redirect('/account/login')
    return render(request, 'Account/register.html')
```

My question is how to check if username is already exist in my table when user register a account and show the error "username is already taken "in template html page

I'm stuck here, please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    def register(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
            middle_name = request.POST.get('middle_name')
            last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
            password2 = request.POST.get('password2')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            club_favorite = request.POST.get('club_favorite')

            # Check if username already exists
            if MyAccount.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.error(request, 'Username already exists')
                return redirect('register')

            # Create a new user
            user = MyAccount.objects.create_user(first_name, middle_name, 
            last_name, username, password1, email, club_favorite)
            user.save()

            return redirect('/account/login')
        return render(request, 'Account/register.html')
```

MyAccount.objects.filter() method to check if the username already exists. If it does, we return an error message and redirect the user back to the register page. If it does not exist, we create a new user using the MyAccount.objects.create_user() method and redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: oke, thank you. but i have one more question. how to check in register.html so if user register an account that have same username in database my website doesnt crash, instead the website show message infromation that username is alreadt taken

Comment: type object 'MyAccount' has no attribute 'objects' at if not MyAccount.objects.filter(username=username).exists():

Answer (score 2):

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
    middle_name = request.POST.get('middle_name')
    last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
    password2 = request.POST.get('password2')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    club_favorite = request.POST.get('club_favorite')
    
    ####### Query the DB if a username not exists 
    if not MyAccount.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
        user = MyAccount.object.create_user(first_name, middle_name, last_name, username, password1, email, club_favorite)
        user.save()
        return redirect('/account/login')
    
    return render(request, 'Account/register.html')
```

Comment: oke, thank you. but i have one more question. how to check in register.html so if user register an account that have same username in database my website doesnt crash, instead the website show message infromation that username is alreadt taken

Comment: I assume, since I am not sure of your project architecture. One possible solution is to change the ".filter" into ".get"
Other possible solution will be to change
'if MyAccount.objects.filter(username=username).count() == 0'

Comment: type object 'MyAccount' has no attribute 'objects' at if not MyAccount.objects.filter(username=username).exists():

Answer (score 0):

you have to import your custom user model, and then query your user database inside your register view.

```
from django.db.models import Q
from models import MyAccount

user = MyAccount.objects.filter(Q(username=username) | Q(email=email)
```

and than just check

```
if user:
    <your code>
```

Comment: type object 'MyAccount' has no attribute 'objects' at if not MyAccount.objects.filter